# Is there valid HTML5 markup when the article header is above the site sidebar?

Tags: html, sidebar

A classic site design for an individual article these days has a full width article header - containing say, the title, sharing links, a banner image etc - as that is the most prominent part of the page.

Underneath that, the article content appears with a site sidebar to its right.

Am I correct that this is basically impossible to achieve with correct HTML5 article / aside markup?

The header and content are both part of the article, so (without using position absolute, which is usually impossible due to variable heights) the article tag must wrap around both.

However, this also means the aside must be within the article tag, while the HTML5 specs say that site sidebars, not directly corresponding to the article, should be outside of the article tag.

Edit - for reference, since the answer is probably yes, it's impossible, I'm wondering what people are choosing as the least evil alternative, since this seems a common design.

Comment: this seems like css question. look for CSS Grid - as for me this seems to be solution for your challange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I have dealt with this for a long time. The rest of the development community seems to put the header above and outside the article and does not question it.

I currently put the header inside the article and use javascript to place the sidebar inside the article and under the header.
CSS Grid wont fix the issue.

Recently I am thinking its easier to pull out the header and out it above with javascript.